# Avoid informing the client if a username exists or not using Meteor.loginWithPassword

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor 1.2.1

Relevant packages include:

- accounts-base@1.2.2
- accounts-password@1.1.4

`Meteor.loginWithPassword(goodUid, badPassword)` will result in an error 403, with a note stating that the password is incorrect.

`Meteor.loginWithPassword(badUid, badPassword)` will result in an error 403, with a note stating that the userId does not exist.

I believe it is bad practice to reveal which usernames are valid/invalid on a login screen. Thus, I would like to know what is a good way to prevent revealing user-id validity during login? I expected I could create a Meteor.method on the server to handle login and return a generic error, but Meteor.loginWithPassword appears to be client only ([source](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword)).

Comment: Can't you alter the error msg on the client before you show it to the user?

Comment: Note that your first question about whether or not it is a security issue is off-topic for SO, it would be more fit on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) (and has probably been asked a lot before). Could you please [edit] that out of your post to only keep your second question? Please also specify which packages you are using. Nice question! Finally, could you create a MeteorPad to show this issue? That would be a nice demonstration. @MichelFloyd Even if so, it doesn't prevent an automated attacker to fetch existing user ids, which is very very bad.

Comment: Correct on the automated attacker @Kyll. It should just return "invalid username/password combination". Maybe I'll make a pull-request with this change.

Comment: Updated post as well as i could. meteorpad does not want to load atm. will try again later.

Comment: After thinking about this a bit I think the best solution is to throttle login requests to defeat script scans. The code in Meteor that handles user validation is [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/5931bcdae362e1026ceb8a08e5a4b053ce5340b7/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js)

Comment: I also think that should happen (regardless). It might be beneficial to allow a flag on login about whether or not you would like the server-side error response to be obfuscated or not.